# in R group service to order numbers within a range in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, dplyr

I have a dataframe of a service. Now I need to add a column "order" and group them with the following rule:

Group the service to orders: If within the next 5 values after one service Value "A" is another service "A" present, fill all values to an order ID - also the ones that don't have a service value. If there is no service value within the next 5 values the next order group is defined.

dput(data)

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
14, 15, 16), time = structure(1:15, .Label = c("13:20:01", "13:20:02", 
"13:20:03", "13:20:04", "13:20:05", "13:20:06", "13:20:07", "13:20:08", 
"13:20:09", "13:20:10", "13:20:11", "13:20:12", "13:20:13", "13:20:14", 
"13:20:15"), class = "factor"), apples = c(2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), service = structure(c(NA, 1L, 1L, 
NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L), .Label = "A", class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

overview

```
id   time       apples   service
1    13:20:01   2        
2    13:20:02   2        A         
3    13:20:03   2        A         
4    13:20:04   3                  
5    13:20:05   3        A         
6    13:20:06   2                  
7    13:20:07   2        A         
8    13:20:08   2                 
9    13:20:09   2                  
10   13:20:10   2                 
11   13:20:11   2                 
12   13:20:12   2
14   13:20:13   2        A         
15   13:20:14   2                  
16   13:20:15   2        A
```

This is the format I'm looking for.  ID 2 to ID 8 is an order and ID 14 to ID 16.

```
id   time       apples   service  Order
1    13:20:01   2        
2    13:20:02   2        A         1
3    13:20:03   2        A         1
4    13:20:04   3                  1
5    13:20:05   3        A         1
6    13:20:06   2                  1
7    13:20:07   2        A         1
8    13:20:08   2                 
9    13:20:09   2                  
10   13:20:10   2                 
11   13:20:11   2                 
12   13:20:12   2
14   13:20:13   2        A         2
15   13:20:14   2                  2
16   13:20:15   2        A         2
```

I tried it with a for loop. I suggest there is a way to use the mutate method and add the "range" conditon.

Thx for your help!

This is my output that is produced by the code of tspano

```
# A tibble: 15 x 11
      id time     apples service start   end g0       g1 g2       g3 order
   <dbl> <fct>     <dbl> <fct>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <int> <chr> <int> <int>
 1     1 13:20:01      2 NA          0     3 NA        0 NA        0    NA
 2     2 13:20:02      2 A           1     3 start     1 NA        0    NA
 3     3 13:20:03      2 A           2     3 NA        1 NA        0    NA
 4     4 13:20:04      3 NA          2     2 NA        1 NA        0    NA
 5     5 13:20:05      3 A           3     2 NA        1 NA        0    NA
 6     6 13:20:06      2 NA          3     1 NA        1 NA        0    NA
 7     7 13:20:07      2 A           3     1 NA        1 NA        0    NA
 8     8 13:20:08      2 NA          2     0 end       2 NA        0    NA
 9     9 13:20:09      2 NA          2     1 NA        2 NA        0    NA
10    10 13:20:10      2 NA          1     1 NA        2 NA        0    NA
11    11 13:20:11      2 NA          1     2 NA        2 NA        0    NA
12    12 13:20:12      2 NA          0     2 NA        2 NA        0    NA
13    14 13:20:13      2 A           1     2 start     3 NA        0    NA
14    15 13:20:14      2 NA          1     1 NA        3 NA        0    NA
15    16 13:20:15      2 A           2     1 NA        3 NA        0    NA
```

Comment: Please provide a `dput` of your data frame and also add your code so that we can see what you have tried.

Comment: Hi Mus, I added my code (above) that I have so far. I don't know how to implement the "range" in the ifelse statement.

Comment: Please also provide the output of `dput(data)` so that this can be replicated.

Comment: You've misunderstood. Type `dput(data)` into your console and then copy and paste the output of that function into your question so that we can replicate your data frame.

Comment: I have over 170mio observations., A for loop is not really time efficient. Is the mutate method the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using `RcppRoll`, which should be faster than a R for loop:

```
data %>% 
  mutate(start = RcppRoll::roll_sum(c(rep(F,4),(service=="A") %in% T), n = 5, align = "right"),
         end = RcppRoll::roll_sum(c((service=="A") %in% T, rep(F,4)), n = 5, align = "left"),
         g0 = case_when(start>0 & (lag(start)==0) %in% c(T,NA) ~ "start",
                        end ==0 ~ "end",
                        T ~ NA_character_)
  ) %>% 
  group_by(g1 = cumsum(!is.na(g0))) %>% 
  mutate(g2 = if_else(first(g0)=="end", NA_character_, "order")) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(g3 = cumsum(!is.na(g2) & is.na(lag(g2))) ) %>% 
  mutate(order = if_else(is.na(g2), NA_integer_, g3)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  select(id, time, apples, service, order)
```

If you remove the last `select` you can see I have several intermediate results that should make the logic clear.

Comment: I get the error: Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, col, value = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  : 
  replacement has 1255643 rows, data has 1255728

Comment: I guess this could happen if you change the `n=5` parameter in the `roll_sum`. The `rep(F,4)` should also be changed since it should be `n-1` and not 4

Comment: Ah, yes! If I run the code with the sample data, I get only NA values for the order.

Comment: That's strange; I get your desired output using `data` defined as in your `dput` output

Comment: I removed the select (...) and added the output to the Question. Could it be, that an other method has also the same name?  -> Do I have to write for example: RcppRoll::cumsum

Comment: That can be. Looking at your output, the computation of `g2` is not as expected, before that it is fine so it is not about `roll_sum`. Both `first` and `if_else` are assumed from package `dplyr` in my code.

Comment: mutate(g2 = if_else(first(g0)=="end", NA_character_, "order")) is the "order" correct?

Comment: That doesn't really matter, it is just a binary variable. If you see `g2` is only used within `is.na()` so `"order"` is just a random non-NA value

Comment: Eii. It was the mutate method. Now it works. I have to use: dplyr::mutate ...Thx a lot tspano!